# Error linking when using C printf function in assembly in visual studio

Tags: c, assembly, visual-studio-2013

I am using visul studio 2013 and have the following assembly code in which I am trying to use the C function printf:

```
    .386
    .model flat, c
    .stack 100h

    printf  PROTO arg1:Ptr Byte

            .data
    msg1    byte "Hello WOrld!", 0Ah, 0

            .code
    main    proc
            INVOKE printf, ADDR msg1
            ret
    main    endp
            end
```

I get a linker error stating error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _printf. I think that I need to link stdio.h to my assembly in some way but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: No, you need to link in the microsoft runtime lib

Comment: @OldProgrammer How exactly do I do that?